Define a regex pattern to remove all special characters but with an exception included to keep middle dash in compound words like 'self-restraint'
This is the problem: I'm trying to clean a text from all the special characters but want to keep the compound words like 'self-restraint' or 'e-mail' united as they are, with the middle dash. The problem is that this hyphen is recognized as a special character. I have python 3.10
I used several regex patterns to do it, but none worked fine.
import re

text = "This is -a -! -sample- ? e-mail text?classification? example- ! ?\} {]}[¿ with !self-restraint( - like @, #, and $."

# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'(?<!\b[a-zA-Z]+)-|[^\w\s-]', ' ', text)
cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\W+(?![a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\W+[^\w]', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'(?!\b[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'(?!\b[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)\W+', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\b(?![a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b)\w*[^a-zA-Z\s-]+\w*\b', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+\b', ' ', text)
# cleaned_text = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)-(?!\w)|[^\w\s-]|[^\w\s-]$', ' ', text)

print(cleaned_text)

Actual output:
This is a sample  e mail text classification example with !self restraint like and
Expected output:
This is a sample e-mail text classification example with self-restraint like and

Is it really a requirement that the input text string may contain invalid escape sequences, like "}" ?

@CharlesKnell it is not necessary, I just put it as another special character

You could try something like this:
import re

text = "This is -a -! -sample- ? e-mail text?classification? example- ! ?\} {]}[¿ with !self-restraint( - like @, #, and $."
cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[-]|[-](?!\S)|[^\w\s-]', ' ', text)).strip()

print(cleaned_text)

Output
This is a sample e-mail text classification example with self-restraint like and

Without more examples I can't definitively say whether or not it will succeed on other strings, although this should give you an idea of one possible way to approach this issue.

This is good and actually has result that OP expects, but for me its not clear why text?classification? should result in text classification (with a space) and not textclassification. From my understanding it was only dashes in middle of word that was mentioned. I might be missing something, however.

One approach is to use a helper function to process each word, like so:
import string

# Create a translation table that maps punctuation characters (plus ¿) to None
trans_punc = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation + '¿')

# Create a translation table that maps punctuation characters (except dash) to None
trans_punc_except_dash = trans_punc.copy()
del trans_punc_except_dash[ord('-')]


def remove_special_characters(word):
    return word.translate(trans_punc)


def remove_special_characters_except_dash(word):
    return word.translate(trans_punc_except_dash)


def process_sentence(text):
    r = []
    for word in text.split(' '):
        if 0 < word.find('-') < (last_char_idx := len(word) - 1) and word[last_char_idx] != '-':
            r.append(remove_special_characters_except_dash(word))
        elif cleaned := remove_special_characters(word):
            r.append(cleaned)
    return ' '.join(r)


# Example usage
text = r"This is -a -! -sample- ? e-mail text?classification? example- ! ?\} {]}[¿ with !self-restraint( - like @, #, and $."

result = process_sentence(text)
print(result)

# Check result is as expected
expected = 'This is a sample e-mail textclassification example with self-restraint like and'
assert result == expected

